# How to implement [] operator overloading in cuda program?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am implementing a `device_vector` in Cuda and i am taking ideas from the well known library [Thust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust).

Now for accessing and modifying an element in that `device_vector` (v), I need to do v[N] = x. For that i need to overload the [] operator.

This is the code used to overload the [] operator :

```
T& operator[] (unsigned int index)
{
    if (index >= numEle)
        return ptr[0];
    else
        return ptr[index];
}
```

The problem is : **To modify any memory location in Device Memory, we need to make a Cuda Kernel Call and a Cuda kernel call cannot return anything.**

As far the [] overloading is concerned it returns the reference to the element we want to modify.

How can we do this for a Cuda Kernel ?

Note : I know Thrust Library somehow does this but I am not able to understand how.

Comment: You can return a temporary object that allows conversion to and assignment from `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Kos i could not understand...can you please give me some more details.

Comment: Is this function supposed to run on the host or the device?

Comment: The operator will be used from the host. But to modify the memory in the device we need to make a kernel call.

Comment: @talonmies also, if we use this overloading inside the device, it will give no problem as the address spaces are same. But when we use it from the host we get a segmentation fault.

Comment: No you don't need to run a kernel to modify the memory on the device. That is what the APIs  are for

Comment: so which function should i use of Cuda to do this...?

Comment: `cudaMemcpy` is one possibility.  [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8).  Note that you can discover a lot about how thrust does things by learning to use the `nvprof` profiler.  [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract).

Comment: @RobertCrovella The problem is I have to overload the operator. I will look in to nvprof's output. But can you show me some code on how to go about overloading this [] operator...?

Comment: @RobertCrovella also..i just checked nvprof's result. When I am using v[N] it just says the kernel name which was launched : `[CUDA memcpy DtoH]`

Comment: That isn't the kernel name that was launched.  I'm not disputing that thrust may use kernel launches to get various things done, but in your test case the kernel launch line in the `nvprof` output *precedes* the `[CUDA memcpy DtoH]` line.  The kernel launch you are witnessing is occurring at instantiation of the `thrust::device_vector`.  The `[CUDA memcpy DtoH]` is the way nvprof reports that a `cudaMemcpy` operation occurred (not a kernel launch) and the specified direction of that operation was `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` (which occurs as a result of your `v[N]` "dereference").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have very good pointers, but as an example, you can create an object that will allow you to use the `[]` operator to write to the CUDA array directly (or do any other things you choose):

```
struct CudaVector {

    unsigned int get(unsigned int index) {
        cout << "Get from device: " << index << endl;
        return 0; // TODO read actual value
    }
    void set(unsigned int index, unsigned int value) {
        cout << "Set in device: " << index << " " << value << endl;
        // TODO write actual value
    }

    struct Item {
        CudaVector& vector;
        unsigned int index;
        operator unsigned int() const {
            return vector.get(index);
        }       
        unsigned int operator=(unsigned int other) {
            vector.set(index, other);
            return other;
        }
        unsigned int operator=(const Item& other) {
            return (*this = static_cast<unsigned int>(other));
        }
    };

    Item operator[](unsigned int index) {
        return Item{*this, index};
    }
};
```

This works like:

```
CudaVector vector;
unsigned int foo = vector[8];
vector[5] = vector[6] = vector[7];
```

Output:

> Get from device: 8
>   Get from device: 7
>   Set in device: 6 0
>   Set in device: 5 0

Idea is that your `operator[]` doesn't return a reference, but instead it returns a temporary object that is able to handle 'reads' (using the conversion operator) and 'writes' (using the assignment operator).

(The second overload is there to allow chained assignments, since the first one won't be picked up automatically if you don't assign from `unsigned int` first.)

Comment: This was really Helpful. Thanks a lot Sir.